# Cherry picking a commit that was overwritten by a push force

Tags: git, gitlab, git-cherry-pick

These are the commits on a branch on origin:

```
A -> B -> C1
```

Locally, I had the branch when it only had `A -> B` commits and I add a new commit. So the branch locally looks like:

```
A -> B -> C2
```

I do a push force and overwrite the remote branch so it removes `C1` commit and replaces it with `C2`.

Is it possible to get `C1` back and add it back to the branch?

I tried with cherry pick, but I get `fatal: bad revision`. However, I was able to cherry pick it using gitlab's web interface. Is this possible without gitlab?

Comment: You can look at the commits in remote by either `git log` or with `git rev-list --remotes`. From there I guess you can cherry-pick whatever you want. Of course you do neet to fetch the remote in order to know the commits

Comment: Can you explain how yo are running the cherry-pick and the output from it? `git cherry-pick C1` should be good enough to get something like `A -> B -> C2 -> C1'` (notice how I wrote **C1'**, not C1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find a repository that actually has the commit in it.

Clearly, *your* repository didn't:

> I tried with cherry pick, but I get `fatal: bad revision`

Clearly their repository (the one you force-pushed to) *had* it before.  Whether they still do depends on (a) whether the commit was reachable by some other means, and if not, (b) how aggressive they are about garbage-collecting unreachable commits.

If there are other users of the upstream repository, those other users may have copied the commit into their repositories.

Note that when you do obtain `C1` again and use `cherry-pick` on it, you get a new and different commit that *has the same effect as* `C1`, and the same author as `C1`, but you as the committer.  You could call this `C3`, or—to indicate how similar it is to the original `C1`—you could call it `C1'`.  As [eftshift0 noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2437508/eftshift0), the end result is:

```
A <-B <-C2 <-C1'   <-- branch
```

If other people still have commit `C1`, they may attempt to re-introduce it.  This will usually be harmless: depending on how they make this attempt, it might either just *remove* their copy, or it might make a merge that has no effect:

```
     C2--C1'
    /      \
A--B        M   <-- branch
    \      /
     --C1--
```

This sort of thing is why it's generally unwise to rebase and/or force-push-away other people's commits.  If they're not expecting it, they'll re-introduce their commits, even though you've made new commits that subsume their work.

If all users of all of the various clones of these repositories agree that rebasing / cherry-picking and force-pushing *do* get used on this branch name, then in that case it's fine.  It's up to each user to notice that this has happened (if necessary) and do whatever is required (if anything) to compensate for it.